# moving object using slider openCV c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm very new to OpenCV (c++), my lecturer ask me to make a simple slider that every position in slider have different place in the window. My code below can move the object in window based on slider position but when i moved the slider the old position still there. So it looks like a duplicate not move. Can anyone help me on this problem?? Are there a way to solve this problem or I must change the code completely??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h" 
#include "ml.h" 
#include "cxcore.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 


int g_switch_value = 0; 
int colorInt = 0; 

void switch_callback( int position ){ 
    if( position == 0 ){ 
        colorInt = 0; 
    }else{ 
        colorInt = 1; 
    } 
} 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{ 
const char* name = "Change the color of circle in the picture"; 
int radius = 30; 
int thickness = 12; 
int connectivity = 8; 
cvscalar red = cv_RGB(0,0,255); 

IplImage* src1 = cvLoadImage( "E:/2.jpg" ); 

CvPoint pt1 = cvPoint(405,195); 
CvPoint pt2 = cvPoint(620,400);

cvNamedWindow( name, 1 ); 
cvShowImage(name, src1); 

cvCreateTrackbar( "Change", name, &g_switch_value, 1, switch_callback ); 

while( 1 ) { 
    if( colorInt == 0) { 
        cvCircle(src1,pt1,radius,red,thickness,connectivity);}
    else { 
        cvCircle(src1,pt2,radius,red,thickness,connectivity); }
        colorInt == 1;
        cvShowImage(name, src1); 
    if( cvWaitKey( 15 ) == 27 )  break; 
} 
cvReleaseImage( &src1 ); 
cvDestroyWindow( name ); 

return 0; }
```

Comment: Do you mean when you move the trackbar it creates a new circle at the right position but also keeps the old one? Could it be maybe that you're creating a new circle each time the trackbar is moved, but you also need to delete the old one by changing its color? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Drawing overwrite the image, then you should keep a fresh copy for each different painting. 
The easier way:

```
IplImage* src1 = cvLoadImage( "..." );
IplImage* src2 = cvLoadImage( "..." );
...

while( 1 ) {
    if( colorInt == 0) {
        cvShowImage(name, src1);
        cvCircle(src1,pt1,radius,red,thickness,connectivity);
    }
    else {
        cvShowImage(name, src2);
        cvCircle(src2,pt2,radius,red,thickness,connectivity);
    }
    if( cvWaitKey( 15 ) == 27 )  break;
}
cvReleaseImage( &src1 );
cvReleaseImage( &src2 );
```